# JavaScript: Full page scroll

Tags: javascript

So, this code is working as intended. But, it can sometimes glitch.

What I want:

User swipes downward, and then the next page comes into view. I already have an animation for the pages. I just need to add or remove a class depending on the swipe direction and it has to apply to the right page (screen).

Here is the js code I am using:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  window.scroll(0, 0)
  var pages = document.querySelectorAll('section.page'),
    currentPage = 0,
    totalPages = pages.length - 1,
    watchScroll = true // check scroll direction

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (watchScroll) {
      if (this.oldScroll < this.scrollY) {
        // currently scrolling down
        if (currentPage < totalPages) {
          handlePageDown()
        }
      } else {
        // currently scrolling up
        if (currentPage > 0) {
          handlePageUp()
        }
      }
    }
    this.oldScroll = this.scrollY
  })

  function handlePageDown() {
    pages[currentPage].classList.add('down-scroll')
    nextPage = currentPage + 1
    resetScroll(function() { // here, reset the scroll near the top so that the 
                             // user has room to scroll up or else it will go
                             // fully to the top or bottom when they scroll



      setCurrentPage(nextPage) // set the next target div
    })
  }

  function handlePageUp() { // same as down but reverse node index
    pages[currentPage - 1].classList.remove('down-scroll')
    nextPage = currentPage - 1
    resetScroll(function() {
      setCurrentPage(nextPage)
    })
  }

  function resetScroll(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      watchScroll = false // don't pay attention to the scroll reset or this will trigger the eventListener
      window.scroll(0, 10) // reset scroll position to give room for up or down
      callback()
    }, 50)
  }

  function setCurrentPage(setPageAs) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      currentPage = setPageAs
      watchScroll = true
    }, 400)
  }
})
```

Thoughts on how to make this without relying on `setTimeout()` keep in mind, that without a delay, it will apply the class instantly to all the matching divs.

Comment: Are these "pages" sections on a page?  If so, are you looking for scroll snapping (https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/)?  If not, what detail am I overlooking that differentiates it?

Comment: Have you test scroll magic?

Comment: @SephReed Hey, actually, I think this will work. Haha, thanks, I'll give it a shot

Comment: @EzequielFernandez I have not, I thought I would try to just use javascript

Comment: You can use js, but using css will let the browser use compiled "native" code, which is always more efficient.

Comment: @SephReed fair point.

Comment: @SephReed Yeah, that worked, do you want to make a quick answer I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't completely consider this an answer to the question (as it was asked), it appears to be the overall best solution to the problem.

**Css Scroll Snapping**

The number of combinations of scroll snapping are such that they won't really fit in an answer, but here's some example css which would work really well if all the sections are 300px tall.

```
.container {
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(300px);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

To learn more about it, check out css-tricks : https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/

or to get into the weeds, mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap